# hovering over contents of navigation bar causes whole bar to expand

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying for hours to figure out why my dropdown menu is expanding whenever I hover over it. The bar expands to the length of the list of dropdown contents and goes right back to normal when I move my mouse. When I tried to fix this by making the bar's position absolute, it led to the contents of the navigation bar being blocked by my background image. To fix the bar being hidden by the other elements on the page, I tried playing around with the z-index values (setting the value of my background image to -1, and the value of my menu to 10, 200, 999, etc.) but nothing is working! As you can see, for the navbar I used W3 tools, but I checked and their classes don't define z-values for any of the navbar's elements, or make the bar's position static, so I doubt it has to do with that. If there is a simpler way to construct it though, I'm all ears.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Shop</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka One">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com">
<body>
    <!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
    <div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-wide w3-padding w3-card">
    <a href="index.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button logo">Logo</a>
    <!-- Float links to the right. Hide them on small screens -->
    <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop A</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
    

<a href="pages/a1.php">A1</a>
    <a href="pages/a2.php">A2</a>
    <a href="pages/a3.php">A3</a>
    <a href="pages/a4.php">A4</a>
    <a href="pages/a5">A5</a>
      </div>
    </div>
           


      <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop B</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
            <a href="pages/b1.php">B1</a>
            <a href="pages/b2.php">B2</a>
            <a href="pages/b3.php">B3</a>
            <a href="pages/b4.php">B4</a>
            <a href="pages/b5.php">B5</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop C</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
            <a href="pages/c1.php">C1</a>
            <a href="pages/c2.php">C2</a>
            <a href="pages/c3.php">C3</a>
            <a href="pages/c4.php">C4</a>
            <a href="pages/c5.php">C5</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop D</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content reddo-font">
            <a href="pages/d1.php">D1</a>
            <a href="pages/d2.php">D2</a>
            <a href="pages/d3.php">D3</a>
            <a href="pages/d4.php">D4</a>
            <a href="pages/d5.php">D5</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
    <div class="header">
    <img class="header-img" src="mast2.jpg">
    </div>
     
      <div class="w3-display-middle w3-margin-top w3-center">
        <h1 class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-white"><span class="w3-padding logo"><b>Shop</b></span></h1>
      </div>
      
    </header>
<!-- Page content -->
<div class="w3-content w3-padding" style="max-width:1564px">

  <!-- Shop Section -->
  <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="shopA">
    <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16 w3-center shop-header">Shop A</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="top-img-space">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle button-bottom r-font-white border">
        <a href="pages/clothing">Clothing</a>
        </div>
        
        <img src="clothing.jpg" alt="Clothing" style="width:100%">
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-img-space">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle button-bottom reddo-font-white border">
        <a href="pages/makeup">Makeup</a>
        </div>
        <img src="clothing.jpg" alt="Makeup" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-img-space">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle button-bottom reddo-font-white border">
        <a href="pages/skin+hair">Skin + Hair</a>
        </div>
        <img src="clothing.jpg" alt="Skin + Hair" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-img-space">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle button-bottom r-font-white border">
        <a href="pages/accessories">Accessories</a>
        </div>
        <img src="clothing.jpg" alt="Accessories" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  

 <div class="top-img-space">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle button-bottom r-font-white border">
        <a href="pages/household">Household</a>
        </div>
        <img src="clothing.jpg" alt="Household" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="top-img-space">
      <div class="w3-display-container">
        <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle button-bottom reddo-font-white border">
        <a href="pages/resources">Resources</a>
        </div>
        <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5d3b3ed8084b6f00015405ba/1565292809235-XZT8EMYC8YNFNGLGWJKE/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kNelEQHH6ObyKXhPVtuHdZJ7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QPOohDIaIeljMHgDF5CVlOqpeNLcJ80NK65_fV7S1URRnb5gEg87j_u_CnS6lshZ4YkRnSBu_Tm16f7Acf5j6LgOZgZlG0NTwuNC4AvKbWw/20140302_Trade%2B151_0503.jpg" alt="Resources" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
       



<!-- End page content -->
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Relevant CSS code:

```
 p{
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Mulish";
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Mulish";
}

.r-logo {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Fredoka One";
  font-size: 62px;
  color: #ffff99;
}

.w3-button.r-logo {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: "Fredoka One";
    font-size: 22px;
}

.r-font {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Mulish";
}

.r-font-white {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Mulish";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 1500;
  padding-top: 4%;
  
}

.r-font-white a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.w3-button.r-font {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Mulish";
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.shop-header {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Bungee";
  font-size: 50px;
}

.about-header {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Bungee";
  font-size: 35px;
}

.w3-display-bottommiddle.button-bottom {
  bottom: 5%;
}

.border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-width: thin;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropbtn {
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ffff; color: #3e8e41;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #ffff;}

.top-img-space {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}




.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` on `.dropdown-content`, Like this:

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Also remove `position: relative;`  from `.dropdown`:

```
.dropdown {
/*   position: relative; */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

---

```css
.r-logo {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Fredoka One";
  font-size: 82px;
  color: #a9f5f2;
}

.w3-button.r-logo {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Fredoka One";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
}

.header-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.dropbtn {
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; //  This
  background-color: #ffff;
  width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ffff;
  color: #a9f5f2;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
<div class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-wide w3-padding w3-card">
    <a href="index.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button logo">Logo</a>
    <!-- Float links to the right. Hide them on small screens -->
    <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop A</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content r-font">


          <a href="pages/a1.php">A1</a>
          <a href="pages/a2.php">A2</a>
          <a href="pages/a3.php">A3</a>
          <a href="pages/a4.php">A4</a>
          <a href="pages/a5">A5</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop B</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
          <a href="pages/b1.php">B1</a>
          <a href="pages/b2.php">B2</a>
          <a href="pages/b3.php">B3</a>
          <a href="pages/b4.php">B4</a>
          <a href="pages/b5.php">B5</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop C</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
          <a href="pages/c1.php">C1</a>
          <a href="pages/c2.php">C2</a>
          <a href="pages/c3.php">C3</a>
          <a href="pages/c4.php">C4</a>
          <a href="pages/c5.php">C5</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop D</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content reddo-font">
          <a href="pages/d1.php">D1</a>
          <a href="pages/d2.php">D2</a>
          <a href="pages/d3.php">D3</a>
          <a href="pages/d4.php">D4</a>
          <a href="pages/d5.php">D5</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Header -->
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <img class="header-img" src="mast2.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-margin-top w3-center">
    <h1 class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-white"><span class="w3-padding logo"><b>Shop</b></span></h1>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: I mentioned in my post that I changed the position before and the dropdown part of the menu gets hidden behind the image directly below it. Tried just now and I'm still having the same issue :(

Comment: @anon You mentioned that you changed the position of the bar (i.e. `.dropdown`). And I told to change the position of the `.dropdown-content`...

Comment: @anon This is what you wanted right: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/OJWyRRq?editors=1100

Comment: Yes, I changed the position of .dropdown-content and it's unfortunately hiding the entire dropdown menu behind the image

Comment: I will try copying the code you linked exactly

Comment: @anon You want this right:  https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/OJWyRRq?editors=1100

Comment: Just copied and pasted and it's still not working. the dropdown part of the menu is hidden behind every element on the page, it stays that way even when I scroll down. The navigation bar itself remains visible though, even when I scroll down

Comment: @anon can you provide the image link

Comment: @anon Have you shared the complete code with us or not because there might be some other code interfering...

Comment: I just updated the post with the code I have so far! For the header image instead of the file I have saved on my computer, I used a public squarespace photo

Comment: @anon Remove `position: relative;` from `.dropdown`. Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/eYgpvxE